# Solved: No results for /sites?search= using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

Using Microsoft Graph, I want to search for SharePoint sites containing specific names and moreover I want to get a list of all SharePoint sites.

I am using the following URL in the Graph Explorer:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=test

or

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*

When using an account from Company A everything works. I receive a list of all results.

But when using an account from Company B, I get a 404 NOT FOUND response for all queries (although there should be multiple results):

```html
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-01-01T14:59:35",
            "request-id": "xxxxxx",
            "client-request-id": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it has something to do with the rights of the users?
I tested with "normal" users at both companies.

**Edit:**

I also get an error (403 Access denied) using the following url:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root

But when accessing a specific site by it's id, everything works.

**Edit 2**

I noticed a relationship with the permissions of the root SharePoint site. If the user has no permission for that site, the mentioned queries are not working. I need to contact the admin of the system to check my suspicion.

Comment: I'm facing this exact issue. Did you end up solving it?

Comment: Yes, it was resolved by giving the user the permission to read the root SharePoint site (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/url-that-resides-under-root-site-collection-is-broken).